# Is Raspberry Pi powerful enough to run a laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am currently working on a php project and we are considering to use laravel . Our product will have to run on raspberry pi and we were wondering whether the pi is powerful enough to handle a small laravel app or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

Any Raspberry Pi model can run a web server, such as `Apache + PHP` or `Nginx + PHP`, to serve a Laravel application.

A recent Raspberry Pi with higher specs will provide faster response times compared to an older model with slower CPU and lower amount of RAM.

Another limitation to consider when self hosting an application is network speed. Home connections are often much slower and less reliable than what you would typically get from a cloud provider. If you have multiple users, network speed will likely be your first limiting factor before the Raspberry Pi hardware.